# Marker with Text Inside, Is this possible?

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, marker, markers

I'm building a map and I need to show my markers with a number inside.

Something like this[image: marker with number]

The number will be dinamic and all the markers are inside of a cluster.

Is it possible? Any idea?

Answer (score -1):

You can set background drawables on TextViews. This will achieve what you're after.